# Factory Method - Unknown parameters

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to use the command pattern for the first time, and with it create a command factory, I'm following guidance from a pluralsight.com course where he implements an interface for the factory which includes a MakeCommand method.

Now my issue comes from the fact that he simply passes an array of string as the arguments for this method (his is a command line app), however my commands will use a variety of arguments of a variety of types, my plan was to use these commands to store updates to models, so if the application cannot connect to the services, the commands will be queued for when the connection comes back.

This has always been a little bit of a sticking point for me with generic interfaces, how do i handle the multitude of possible arguments?

My first thought was to pass the model itself, with a simple string argument with the command type (Delete, Update, etc) however since my models do not have any common base class or interface i'm left with a similar problem.

Am i missing something basic here?

EDIT : Example of my problem was requested.

I have a CommandFactory Interface as such

```
 public interface ICommandFactory
{
    string CommandName { get; }
    string Description { get; }

    ICommand MakeCommand( ..arguments.. )
}
```

And i have simple models such as (pure example)

```
public class Model1
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}


public class Model2
{
    public DateTime Time {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set}
}
```

If i wanted to create a command that for example updated a model1, i'm left wondering how the Interface's MakeCommand should look, i can't do MakeCommand(string cmdType, Model1 model) because i have multiple different models which share no common baseclass/interface

Comment: I would try to make a new interface that contains methods related to getting the arguments. If that really doesn't fit your model, have a look at variadic parameters.

Comment: Your problem is unclear to me. Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: Sure, two seconds while i edit.

Comment: Could you provide a link and time offset to the Pluralsight course please as I'm not entirely sure what you want. Thanks Dan.

Comment: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/exercise-files/patterns-library
It is the command pattern module.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the individual models to define how they can be updated. In that case, can you not pass a Function/Action from the Model to the MakeCommand?

```
public class Model
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public void UpdateModel() {...}
}

 public interface ICommandFactory
{
    string CommandName { get; }
    string Description { get; }

    ICommand MakeCommand(Action<Model>);
    ICommand MakeCommandFunc(Func<Model, bool>);
}

public class Command : ICommand
{
    Action<Model> _action;
    Command(Action<Model> action)
    {
       _action = action;
    }

    Execute()
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As requested, use common interface class to model all classes

```
public interface IModel
{
    void UpdateModel();
}

public class Model1 : IModel
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}

   // implement updating of the model
   public void UpdateModel() {...do model update...}
}


public class Model2 : IModel
{
    public DateTime Time {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set}

   // 'dummy' implement updating of the model if this model does not supports updating
   public void UpdateModel() { // do nothing or throw NotImplementedException(); }
}

public interface ICommandFactory
{
    string CommandName { get; }
    string Description { get; }

    ICommand MakeCommand( IModel model );
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what i want. The command would call repositories that update the model, I simply want to be able to pass any of my models into the command factory. But since they have no common ancestor or interface I'm not sure how to pass the different model.

Comment: in that case you'll need to pass a common interface (can be empty too) IModel etc to link all such models. Or (not a good idea), pass Models as an object to the command factory

Comment: That was my original thought! but then i read so many comments about empty interfaces being really bad code smell. Hence this question.

Comment: Agree, an Interface is required that will be inherited by all of the models. And passing Models as object will break the flexibility you desire because it means that you will have to cast back to that object/Model by doing some  conditional tests or reflection which can get nasty.

Comment: Would one of you guys like to post an answer about using the blank interface and I'll mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @user1412240: edit the post, maybe that's what you are looking for. Its not truly empty as with simple empty interface, you'll have to use reflection/casting to figure out which Model classs it represents at runtime and that's not pretty

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use command pattern, this pattern use receiver as object which contains arguments, in your `receiver` you can add list or dictionary of objects.

In this site you can find source code

link : http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Comment: So your suggestion is to avoid using the factory pattern with the command pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the ICommandFactory interface generic like so:

```
    public interface ICommandGeneric
{
    void execute();
}

public class CommandOnModel1 : ICommandGeneric
{
    private Model1 model;
    public CommandOnModel1(Model1 model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(model.ToString());
    }
}

public interface ICommandFactory <in ModelType>
{
    string CommandName { get; }
    string Description { get; }

    ICommandGeneric MakeCommand(ModelType model, string parameter1);
}

public class Model1
{

}

public class Model1CommandFactory : ICommandFactory<Model1>
{

    public string CommandName
    {
        get { return "CommandOnModel1"; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return "I do stuff on Model1"; }
    }

    public ICommandGeneric MakeCommand(Model1 model, string parameter1)
    {
        return new CommandOnModel1(model);
    }
}
```

Having said that, I am not entirely sure you should use a factory and maybe not even the command pattern here.

Comment: I'm beginning to think the factory pattern is actually more of a problem, but why do you suggest i shouldn't use the command pattern, it seems to be a good fit for solving my original problem (queuing edits, deletes etc for execution when the net connection returns).

Comment: @user1412240 You haven't really described your original problem, so I can't say for certain. Perhaps the command pattern is the best choice.